# prevent iframe content reload on hide in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, reload

In my webapplication I hide an iframe using jquery hide() function.
Surprisingly firefox reload the content of iframe when the iframe is hidden.
Is this a known problem? Is there a workaround?
I also tried to hide the iframe setting css style display to 'none'. Same result.

The script work as expected in opera.

I'm using firefox 3.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about that bug, but one possible solution is to set height and width to 0px instead, maybe?

Comment: of course, I was considering to "hide" the iframe in some other ways.
I've published the question to know if there is a "cleaner" workaround or if it is a bug

Answer (score 2):

Some say the solution might be in providing a different 
id or name attribute for each IFRAME =
but it did not work in my Case (FF 3.6+)

Another possible solution is to make sure the iframe's content
is not taken from the browsers cache.

this can be done by concatenating a randomizing string to the the iframe's source URL, making sure the content will never come from the cache.

all in all, its a bug that should be fixed by the Mozilla team!..